# Execution plan for single iteration of cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I'm using Microsoft SSMS and I'm trying to optimise a particularly complicated cursor that I'm using in a stored procedure.

If I run an execution plan on the whole thing (besides taking forever) every section comes out as 0% of batch because the cursor runs around 1000 iterations and each iteration seems to have its own entry.

How can get the execution plan for just a single iteration of the cursor so I can actually tell what parts of its execution are actually taking the most time?

Incase it's relevant, it's a fast_forward cursor running on a global temp table that does a bunch of selects and updates.

Comment: instead of cursor , if you used a set based approach by using a table variable and passing a set of values to the procedure will speed up the things, also without looking at the code and the execution plan it is impossible to tell where the problem is.

Comment: I suggest a trace for this task.  You can use either SQL Profiler or Extended Events to capture the statement completed events.

Comment: The percentages in the plan (even actual) are just estimates based on estimated number of rows -- and can be totally wrong. Looking at statistics io output usually gives a lot better picture about what's happening. [statisticsparser](http://statisticsparser.com) is a good help on that.

Comment: "...a particularly complicated cursor..." Imagine that the results of your query are like building a house out of bricks. You're currently set up so that the brick truck delivers the bricks to the site one at a time. You've asked for help on how to make the brick truck go faster. You might get better performance if you can get your bricks delivered in a SET. If you posted a different question enunciating the overall business process and what you want to do, you might get better a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add TOP 1 to your CURSOR SELECT query.
This will only return one 1 record to the cursor allowing you investigate cursor loop a bit better.

e.g.

```
DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT TOP 1 ....
FROM ...
```

I follow below approach to profile cursors:
SQL Server cursors are very slow. If you have a large complex query that declares a cursor you may find that this consumes 50% of the execution time by itself (in FETCH NEXT operations).
The way I profile SPs with cursors is to add execution time counters to the beginning of SP code e.g.

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME
DECLARE @CodeBlock1Duration BIGINT
DECLARE @CodeBlock2Duration BIGINT
SELECT @CodeBlock1Duration = 0, @CodeBlock2Duration = 0
```

etc.
then inside the loop capture execution duration for specific parts as follows:

```
SET @StartTime = GETDATE()
-- Some code block
SET @CodeBlock1Duration = @CodeBlock1Duration + DATEDIFF( ms, @StartTime, GETDATE())
```

Do it in iterations i.e. add few counters first to large chunks of code. Run your SP, then analyse results. For long running chunks of code add more counters around individual queries.
Always add a counter around FETCH NEXT part as this can take more time than you think (see 50% above).